# Method that takes one table and one boolean as parameters

Tags: java, boolean

One more method that takes one table and one boolean as parameters. If this boolean variable is set to “true” this method returns the maximum number in the table, other case returns the minimum number.

How can I do this; can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;    
public class Assignment2 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[][] array = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };          
        yaz(array);
        System.out.println("");
        rakamdanArray(9, 3);        
        }

    public static int[][] rakamdanArray(int m, int n) {    
        int[][] tableArray = new int[m][n];    
        Random r = new Random();    
        for (int a = 0; a < m; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {    
                int rakam = r.nextInt(1000);    
                tableArray[a][b] = rakam;    
                System.out.print(tableArray[a][b] + "|| ");    
            }
                System.out.println(" ");
                    }    
        return tableArray;    
    }
```

Second Step

```
    public static void yaz(int[][] array) {    
        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {    
            for (int b = 0; b < array[0].length; b++) {
                System.out.print(array[a][b] + " ");    
            }    
            System.out.println(" ");       

            {               
            }}  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where is the `table` in parameter ?

Comment: What is your question? We would not like to write the code for you.

Comment: i just want to how can i write the boolean method to this

Comment: show your effort to write the Boolean method ?

Comment: i don't see any method which take table and boolean as parameters . It's a 2d array not table.

Comment: Can you at least write a method signature that takes a boolean and a table(or 2-dim array) parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming by table you mean a 2-dimensional array.
It would make more sense to have sepperate methods to calculate the min and max and call them in a third method.

```
private int getMinMax(int[][] table, boolean max){
    if(max) return max(table);
    else return min(table);
}

private int min(int[][] table){
    int tempMin = int[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j < table[i].length; j++)
            if(table[i][j] < tempMin) tempMin = table[i][j];

    return tempMin;

}

 private int max(int[][] table){
    int tempMax = int[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j < table[i].length; j++)
            if(table[i][j] > tempMax) tempMax = table[i][j];

    return tempMax;

}
```

Comment: now its ok thank you. İ wrote this code in for loop's paranthesis :) how can i call this method in main?

Comment: assuming your Array is called array as in your example then you can make a call like `getMinMax(array, true);` for max or `getMinMax(array, false);` for min. And of course since it returns an int you can call it within a print like `System.out.println(getMinMax(array, true));` etc
Also i see you have accepted an answer that does it with a single method. Since you are obviously new in Java you should get into the habit of breaking things in methods. Generally when you reach around 15 lines of code within a method you should start thinking of breaking the thing into more methods.

Comment: thank you for the help.But I want to write not this int[][] array = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };  ı want to print table's numbers

Comment: I dont think i understand this very last comment. You want to print the min and max value of your 2-dimensional Array called array. Right?

Comment: yeah not that one ->  int[][] array = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } }

Comment: If you want to print the entire table you need a nested for loop. On every step of the outer loop you change line after you print the values. Also you can use the `getMinMax(array, true)` as if it was an int. I don't know what else can you mean with your last comment. If you need more help please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't matter if its this array or an Array called John. When you have you array ready just pass it into the method and it will work

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you :

```
public static int find(int[][] matrix, boolean flag) {
    int ans = 0;

    if (flag) {
        ans = matrix[0][0];
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix[col].length; row++) {
                if (ans < matrix[col][row]) {
                    ans = matrix[col][row];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        ans = matrix[0][0];
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix[col].length; row++) {
                if (ans > matrix[col][row]) {
                    ans = matrix[col][row];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```